# how can i convert the avg values to int, and how can I round up the hours to the days (change 72 days 32:01:52.694268 to just be 73)

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select day_of_week, avg(booking_time)
from(SELECT check_in_date - booked_at as booking_time, EXTRACT (dow FROM 
    check_in_date)day_of_week
    FROM bookings 
    ) as table1
where EXTRACT(epoch FROM booking_time)/3600 > 0
group by day_of_week
order by avg(booking_time) desc;
```

here's the output table:

| day_of_week | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 4.0 | 72 days 32:01:52.694268 |
| 5.0 | 57 days 34:00:09.228322 |
| 3.0 | 50 days 26:30:19.840091 |
| 6.0 | 41 days 33:12:01.010234 |
| 0.0 | 36 days 14:35:36.59173 |
| 2.0 | 34 days 28:15:35.384787 |
| 1.0 | 31 days 10:52:57.718717 |

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer:

```
select  extract(days from justify_hours('72 days 32:01:52.694268'::interval));
73
```

Further explanation. Use `justify_hours` from [DateTime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) to convert the hours portion of the interval to a day if appropriate.

```
select  justify_hours('72 days 32:01:52.694268'::interval);
      justify_hours      
-------------------------
 73 days 08:01:52.694268
```

Then use `extract` from the same link above to pull the days portion of the interval out:

```
select  extract(days from justify_hours('72 days 32:01:52.694268'::interval));
 extract 
---------
      73
```